# Routine exams in patients with hypothyroidism

Tags: blood-tests, endocrinology, thyroid, hypothyroid

In people with hypothyroidism that is being treated with thyroid hormones and that are not showing symptoms or hypothyroidism, how often should these tests be performed:

- TSH blood test
- T4 blood test
- ultrasound of the thyroid
- scintigraphy of the thyroid

(if at all, of course)

If the cause of the hypothyroidism matters, let's say Hashimoto thyroiditis.

Comment: So far, I looked into the Guidelines for the Treatment of Hypothyroidism http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/full/10.1089/thy.2014.0028 but that doesn't seem to include recommendations like what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

This also depends on the question if hypothyroidism is subclinical or overt. Recently, the European Thyroid Association has published a [guideline on the management of subclinical hypothyroidism](http://www.eurothyroid.com/files/download/ETA-Guideline-Management-of-Subclinical-Hypothyroidism.pdf). In asymptomatic patients thyroid function tests (TFTs) should be repeated in 6 months intervals.

Decisions shouldn't be based on TSH levels alone, but also on concentrations of free T4 and free T3. In difficult cases calculated parameters including SPINA-GT, SPINA-GD and Jostel's TSH index might be helpful as well. A [recent paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26335522) demonstrated age, sex, SPINA-GD and aetiology of hypothyroidism to be independent predictors of substitution dose with L-T4.